# use two variables in django template if tag

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

Hi all not sure how to explain this clearly but here goes....

I need to use two variables like so:

```
{% for client in clients %}
    {% if user.client.username %}
```

I need {% if user.username %} but the value of username is in client.username from the loop.

is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to explain better your problem...

Comment: show as your model and tell us what exactly you want to do

Comment: Please explain this more.  If the value you need is in client.username like you say, why can't you use {% if client.username %}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `user` is a dict, and you want to lookup the value indexed by `client` in each iteration of the loop - eg, `user[client].username` in Python.

This (deliberately) isn't possible in Django templates - the language is limited, to force you to do pre-processing in code.

Instead, you should zip your two lists/dicts together before passing them to the template.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something if the value of `client.username` is equal to the value of `user.client.username`? If so, you want:

```
{% if client.username == user.client.username %} # Works in Django 1.2 and above
{% ifequal client.username user.client.username %} # Works everywhere
```

Comment: {% with user.client.username as somevariable %}?